# Writing to files in Android Apps with Rust

Tags: android, rust, adb

I have a game written in Rust and running on my Android phone using `cargo-apk apk run --target=armv7-linux-androideabi` via ADB. It's a simple game and I don't want to create a full authentication system, so I'm just trying to use a local .txt file to store a user id. From what I've seen, there aren't any special permissions required to write to your app's local directory.

I have been googling like crazy, but I haven't found any specific information on writing to the Android file system using Rust. By all accounts, it should "just work".

I get an error of `Read-only file system (os error 30)`.

```
match std::fs::write("id.txt", "123456") {
    Ok(_) => { Log::warn("SUCCESS WRITING ID"); } 
    Err(e) => { Log::warn(format!("ERROR WRITING ID: {}", e)); }
}
```

It appears to be pretty simple in [Java/Kotlin apps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/android-internal-storage-example-tutorial):

```
FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
outputWriter.write(textmsg.getText().toString());
outputWriter.close();
```

Edit: [Repository for reproducing](https://github.com/bocksdin/android-read-write/tree/main)

Comment: Have you confirmed the Java code can touch local files and it is indeed not a permissions issues?

Comment: What directory are you writing to? Android has limited file system access, to prevent apps from editing each other's files.  You only have access to your app's private directories

Comment: @MeetTitan I haven't written any Java code, as I don't know Java. I just linked that snippet as there are thousands of examples in Java/Kotlin.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have attempted `id.txt` (read-only file system), `assets/id.txt` (file or directory doesn't exist), `rust.executor_android/id.txt` (file or directory doesn't exist), `files/id.txt` (file or directory doesn't exist)

Comment: openFileOutput() will write to getFilesDir() so a directory is known. Think that std::fs::write() needs a full path and not only a file name.

Comment: I have created a repository for reproducibility and linked it in the original post.

Comment: Sometimes a root cause is something other than the exact code being examined. Hence the full repository.

@blackapps A full path like this?

        match std::fs::write("rust.executor_android/files/id.txt", "123456") {
            Ok(_) => Log::warn("id.txt created"),
            Err(e) => Log::warn(format!("id.txt not created: {}", e)),
        }

Comment: No that is not a full path for an Android device.

Comment: Didn't know what a full file path entailed for Android specifically. My knowledge has grown @blackapps

Comment: /data/data/<packagename>/files/id.txt

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/id.txt

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files/id.txt

Answer (score 0):

A full file path must be used. This path worked for me: `/data/data/rust.executor_android/files/id.txt`

Formats that work, thanks to @blackapps

1. `/data/data/<packagename>/files/id.txt`
2. `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/id.txt`
3. `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files/id.txt`